# Which 90s "apocalypse" movie has a prostitute with a child?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, apocalypse

In this movie (mid 90s), the main character is a woman who works in the streets, selling her body. The woman has a child who is her only reason to exist and continue living.

Unexpectedly for the viewer, the biblical (non-figurative) apocalypse, starts out of nowhere. I was like WTF, were I watching an adult or a religious movie? From here, the movie was so intense, that I have lost many of the details.

The buildings appear destroyed, one of the apocalypse horsemen is also shown. I remember the woman confronting (maybe) an angel. She said that she doesn't want any paradise, she only wants her child back, yelling in rage.

Well, this was an horror movie to me, but probably is more of a drama.

**Edit: As pointed out in accepted answer, I wrongly put it was about a prostitute. Sorry for that, it was so long ago!**

Comment: try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(2010_film)

Comment: I'll check that one definetily, it develops in the same lines, probably is a remake. I have added to the description an important detail: I seen this in the 90's

Comment: Also too recent, https://horrornews.net/110083/new-film-apocalypse-the-hooker-defends-against-four-horsemen/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots. Oh, that's an interesting one. Seems like I'm feeling a little apocalyptical lol

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Might this be a muddled memory of the 1991 film, *[The Rapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rapture_(1991_film))*?

> Sharon, a young Los Angeles woman, engages in a swinging, libidinous lifestyle. She comes into contact with a sect that advises her that the Rapture is imminent.
>
> In time, she comes to accept this belief herself and becomes a born-again Christian. She then starts living a pious life, eventually marrying and having a daughter, Mary. When her husband Randy is killed in a senseless murder, however, she begins to question the benevolence of God. She believes God has called her to go to the desert to wait for the Rapture, and instead of leaving her daughter safely with friends, she decides Mary must come with her. Foster, a police officer, is concerned for their well-being after they are reduced to stealing food while they wait, but Sharon is insistent that the end is near.
>
> Sharon begins to despair after a period of time, and at her daughter's urging, decides to hasten their ascendance to heaven. She kills Mary with a gunshot but is unable to take her own life afterwards, afraid she will be condemned as having killed herself. She confesses to Foster what she had done and is jailed.
>
> After an apparition of Mary (accompanied by two angels) in the night, the Rapture occurs. While Sharon sits in her cell early the next morning, a loud trumpet blast is heard all over the world, signaling the start of the Rapture. Later on, Sharon and Foster, after driving out into the desert, are both raptured to a purgatory-like landscape. Foster, who had been an atheist his whole life, accepts God and is allowed entrance to Heaven, but Sharon blames God for Mary's death, even though God did not tell her to take Mary with her to the desert, and she cannot renounce her anger at what she sees as God's cruelty. Mary pleads with her to accept God back into her heart so she can join her and Randy in Heaven, but Sharon refuses, choosing to remain alone in the purgatory-like landscape for eternity.

Sharon is not a prostitute, but does engage in a licentious lifestyle. The apocalypse does happen, and Sharon does speak angrily at a heavenly representative about not wanting Heaven, just her child back.

### Trailer

Film found in the list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Horsemen_of_the_Apocalypse_in_popular_culture

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for my confussion that may difficult the search. Thanks

Comment: On a side note, I didn't remember the good cast of this movie! Will be very interesting to see again

Comment: No worries at all. The brain fills in holes with what makes sense. :-D

Comment: Or sometimes with what almost makes sense. For awhile I misremembered the title as *The Pearl*.